# Cartthrob: Member Birthday Fields

Tags: members, cartthrob

I'm trying to map member fields in CartThrob, and I'm having trouble with Birthday.

`{customer_bday_m}` displays {customer_bday_m}
`{customer_bday_month}` (as shown in docs) displays nothing.

There are no options for the birthday day, month and year fields in the CT settings page.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to store custom data on member save or checkout? If so, you will need to add `custom_data[custom_field_name]` as the name for the input.

I don't see anything in their docs about birthdays?

You may want to use [Profile:Edit](http://mightybigrobot.com/products/detail/profile-edit) along with CartThrob as it can save customer data to your member channel entries automatically.

Comment: The docs page I'm talking about is http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/save_customer_info_form/index.html where you can see bday_month, bday_day and bday_year. I'm trying to save the data. My other fields are something like `<input type="text" name="first_name"  value="{customer_first_name}" />` and work perfectly.

Comment: I'm not positive but that data might be specific for certain gateways, not specific to EE members. Does `{custom_data:bday_month}` work?

Comment: It doesn't show anything. This might need to be a feature request for CT... to allow birthday fields to be mappable in the member settings.

Comment: I didn't save the birthday fields because I suppose it's not supported. However your answer is technically correct so I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try the EE's native `bday_m`, `bday_d`, and `bday_y` fields. The [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/member/index.html#birthday) only mentions the combined `{birthday}` tag, but the month / day / year values are stored separately in the database and are accessible via `{bday_m}`, `{bday_d}`, and `{bday_y}`.

To use these tags, you must be within `{exp:member:custom_profile_data}`, or you could use an alternative, such as [Profile:edit](http://mightybigrobot.com/products/detail/profile-edit) ($49, [mentioned by @Siebird above](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/1104/445)).

I know this answer isn't specific to CT, but it may accomplish what you're after.